# The component runs on all pages without being called - Vue Nuxtjs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I am making pages that are loaded through a component. The pages only call the home component. But when I load all the pages (red box) then I load again the component is executed on all the pages. How do I make it only run on the selected page and not on all of them. I am using whatch to capture the parameter change. I will appreciate your help. [image: Cheers[enter image description here][1]][image][image]

Comment: Vue can't load page through component. It is not how it works. You should take a look at some tutorials/docs.

Comment: @bigless Hello, I think you are wrong or you still have not seen the load of components per page

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it using the following

```
created(){
      this.serio = false;
      if (this.$route.path === '/whatsapp') {
        this.serio = true;
      }
    },
    watch: {
      async $route(to, from) {
          this.serio = false;
        if (this.$route.path === '/whatsapp') {
          this.serio = true;
        }
      }
    }
```